# Bat User Selection

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

This is a simple question that I haven't been able to find an answer to. I am running a script that requires user input/selection. Here is the problematic area:

```
echo   W -- WATCH_SCALE
echo   E -- EARRING_SCALE
echo   R -- RING_SCALE
echo   B -- BOX

set /P rnFunc="choose a script: "
for %%I in (W E R B x) do if #%rnFunc%==#%%I goto assign%%I
```

The script works if user inputs the correct letter, however if user inputs an undefined letter such as 'T' the script continues on to the first option instead of breaking. I would like this to only work if the user inputs a W, E, R or B. What would my best option be?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What about adding `goto noassign` or `goto :eof` right after the `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `goto end` right after the `for` statement. Then make a label called `end` after all the other labels should solve your problem. Basically the first encountered label is being executed since it failed the `for` statement.

Comment: There is a built-in label called `:eof` at the end of every batch file; you don't have to define it. You can also do `exit /b` instead of `goto eof`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou being that I don't see the whole file I do not know if OP wants to end or do something else. I just meant end of options.

Comment: Thanks for this simple answer. In this case I do want to go on to other prompts etc. so instead of going to 'end' I have the script move to a more relevant portion of the script.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to take a look at the `CHOICE` command instead.

```
CHOICE [/C choices] [/N] [/CS] [/T timeout /D choice] [/M text]

Description:
    This tool allows users to select one item from a list
    of choices and returns the index of the selected choice.

Parameter List:    /C    choices       Specifies the list of choices to be created.
                       Default list is "YN".

   /N                  Hides the list of choices in the prompt.
                       The message before the prompt is displayed
                       and the choices are still enabled.

   /CS                 Enables case-sensitive choices to be selected.
                       By default, the utility is case-insensitive.

   /T    timeout       The number of seconds to pause before a default
                       choice is made. Acceptable values are from 0 to
                       9999. If 0 is specified, there will be no pause
                       and the default choice is selected.

   /D    choice        Specifies the default choice after nnnn seconds.
                       Character must be in the set of choices specified
                       by /C option and must also specify nnnn with /T.

   /M    text          Specifies the message to be displayed before
                       the prompt. If not specified, the utility
                       displays only a prompt.

   /?                  Displays this help message.

   NOTE:    The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the index of the
   key that was selected from the set of choices. The first choice listed 
   returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.    If the user 
   presses a key that is not a valid choice, the tool    sounds a warning 
   beep. If tool detects an error condition,    it returns an ERRORLEVEL
   value of 255. If the user presses    CTRL+BREAK or CTRL+C, the tool
   returns an ERRORLEVEL value    of 0. When you use ERRORLEVEL parameters 
   in a batch program, list    them in decreasing order.

Examples:    
CHOICE /?    
CHOICE /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."    
CHOICE /T 10 /C ync /CS /D y    
CHOICE /C ab /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."    
CHOICE /C ab /N /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this solution would work but in this case I will go with the answer from @MotKohn as it would be easier to implement. Will consider using 'choice' in the future.